# Will componentDidMount always be called before componentWillUnmount?

Tags: reactjs

Is it guaranteed that the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method will always be executed (and complete) before `componentWillUnmount`?

For example, in my `componentDidMount` method I am registering a subscription:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = subscribe();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
}
```

If `componentDidMount` is *not* guaranteed to execute and complete before `componentWillUnmount` then `this.unsubscribe` is potentially `undefined` and attempting to invoke it will throw a runtime error.

Comment: `componentDidMount` always gets called before `componentWillUnmount`. Have you experienced a situation where that wasn't the case

Answer (score -1):

React class component documentation about `componentDidMount` lifecycle method (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) states:

`This is a good place to set up any subscriptions. If you do that, don’t forget to unsubscribe in componentWillUnmount().`

Based on this, I would say it is guaranteed that `componentDidMount` will always be executed before `componentWillUnmount`, as otherwise most of the unsubscriptions would throw the error you mention.